# ModuleNotFound: No module named 'app'

Tags: python, testing, directory-structure

Let's say I have the following folder structure intended to organize the tests in my project repo:

```
project/
    app.py
    tests/
        test.py
```

`app.py` has a simple addition function:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

`test.py` tests this function:

```
from app import add
import unittest

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        print('Running the test!')
        self.assertEqual(add(3, 4), 7)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I use [nose2](http://nose2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) everything works:

```
mac:project $ nose2
Running the test!
Ran 1 test in 0.000s
Ok
```

The problem is when I try to run `test.py` directly I get the following error:

```
mac:project $ python tests/test.py
ModuleNotFound: No module named 'app'
```

How can I fix this? The reason is I want to use the [coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.4.2/index.html) package to measure code coverage and I'm getting the same error:

```
mac:project $ coverage run tests/test.py
ModuleNotFound: No module named 'app'
```

I've tried `from ..app import app` but I get this error: `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alasdair who had the right idea. I need to add the following to the top of `test.py` to tell python to look for imports in `project`:

```
import os, sys
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(parent_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run `python tests/test.py`, the `tests` directory is on the Python path, but the parent directory is not, so you can't import apps.

You can get the import to work by adding the `project` directory before the imports in `test.py`:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: I tested this with your example code and it worked for me. Print `sys.path` and check whether it contains your `project` folder at the end. If you don’t like changing `sys.path` in your script you can set the Python path as an environment variable, but you must add the `project` directory to the Python path for the import to work.

Comment: You were close! The path you added is `project/tests` but I need to add `project`. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction.

Comment: I've fixed the order of abspath and dirname now.